# Clearing data from rows in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am working on some old C# code that utilizes a Datagrid (not a DataGridView). Without changing everything, I just want to be able to clear the data from an entire row of the Datagrid.

I set the ItemsSource like so:

```
this.dg.ItemsSource = Data;
```

Data is defined like so:

```
public ObservableCollection<DataCollector> Data
    { 
        get { return _Data; } 
    }
```

and then the code uses some recursive methods like FindChild to populate it like this:

```
TextBlock tb;
Binding b = new Binding("val1");
b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
DGTC1.Header = "A";
DGTC1.Binding = b;
tb = FindChild<TextBlock>(dg, "C1TB");
if (tb != null)
    tb.Text = "A";



public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        T foundChild = FindChildRecusive<T>(parent, childName);
        if (foundChild == null)
        {
            Log.logItem(LogType.Error, "ViewRunData", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                "Did not find child: " + childName);
        }
        return foundChild;
    }

    public static T FindChildRecusive<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (parent == null)
        {
            Log.logItem(LogType.Error, "ViewRunData", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                "Did not find parent for child: " + childName);
            return null;
        }
        T foundChild = null;

        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            T childType = child as T;

            if (childType == null)
            {
                foundChild = FindChildRecusive<T>(child, childName);
                if (foundChild != null) break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
                {
                    var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                    if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                    {
                        foundChild = (T)child;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foundChild = FindChildRecusive<T>(child, childName);
                        if (foundChild != null)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return foundChild;
  }
```

Here's a snippit of the xaml file

`<Custom:DataGrid x:Name="dg" Visibility="Hidden" 
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Height="176" 
                CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" 
                Width="785" Canvas.Top="18" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" >
                <Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <Custom:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="sampleIdColumn" Header="Sample ID" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserSort="False" Width="360" 
                        Binding="{Binding Suspect_ID, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="12">
                        <Custom:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Sample ID" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
                                    </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </Custom:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    </Custom:DataGridTextColumn>
                    <Custom:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DGTC1" Width="35" 
                        Binding="{Binding D3S1358Val1, Mode=OneWay}" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserSort="False">
                        <Custom:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="C1TB" Text="">
                                    <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
                                    </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </Custom:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    </Custom:DataGridTextColumn>
                    <Custom:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DGTC2" Width="35" 
                        Binding="{Binding D3S1358Val2, Mode=OneWay}" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserSort="False">
                        <Custom:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Name="C2TB" Text="">
                                    <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
                                    </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </Custom:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    </Custom:DataGridTextColumn>`

How can I clear data from a row after setting the ItemsSource? I looked at the CurrentItem method but can't figure out how I would implement it.

Comment: You might want to show more code

Comment: @SurjitSD sure. anything you are looking for in particular?

Comment: What type is Data? And why and how are you using "FindChild" to populate the DataGrid with data?

Comment: @mm8 I edited my question

Comment: It's still unclear why you are using the FindChild method. How does your XAML look like?

Comment: @mm8 XAML snippit added.

Comment: So what's the thing about FindChild? How is this related to your DataGrid? And which particlar row do you want to clear?

Comment: @mm8 I don't necessarily need to change anything about FindChild. I just want to be able to clear any row when necessary. I just don't know how to clear them.

Comment: What particular row? Or all rows? Do you want to remove the rows or just make all columns blank?

Comment: @mm8 I want to be able to make the columns blank in rows 2-6. But only if certain conditions are met for that row. I have the logic in place for those conditions so don't worry about that. In some cases, I don't want to clear any rows but in other cases I may have to clear some or all of those rows. Does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167438/discussion-between-user2990406-and-mm8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clear a row by either removing the corresponding `Data` item from the `ObservableCollection<Data>`:

```
Data.RemoveAt(0); // 0 is the index of the first row
```

...or by setting all properties of the corresponding `Data` object to some blank values:

```
var row = Data[0];
row.D3S1358Val1 = "";
//...
```

For the latter to work, the `Data` class must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notifications: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If I use the first option do I need to refresh the data?

Comment: If you remove a row? No. The ObservableCollection class takes care of the refreshing for you.

Comment: Okay. And I do this before setting the datagrid.ItemsSource correct?

Comment: Doesn’t matter. There are no rows in the DataGrid before you have set the ItemsSource though.